# Regular Expressions: How to Split On Letters Preceeded by Numbers or

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering what Regular Expression I could use to split a string into an array if the string looked like the following:

```
2x+5=7y^2+x^2+5
```

would come into an array like:

```
[2x,+5,=,7y^2,+x^2,+5]
```

If that didn't make sense. Split on any value including - or + followed by a letter followed by or not followed by a carret and a number followed by a letter. I am asking specifically what formula in Regex I could use

Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you going to do with that array?

Comment: Use `var arr = text.split(/(?=[+=])/g)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` with the following regex:

```js
var s = "2x+5=7y^2+x^2+5",
    res = s.match(/=|[+-]?\d*(?:\w(?:\^\d+)?|\d+)/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, @NinaScholz! ;-)